# What is Difference Between Configurable Product & Simple Product In Magento?

Tags: magento2, php, simple-product

I Can't find any difference in the product types

Comment: You can check this link https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-types.html

Comment: Even though it is Mageno 1, the concept is same